# Bond0 - cannot set the right LB algorithm to 802.3ad

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, systemd, lacp

**Ubuntu 16.04.4**

I'm trying to setup a 4 interface bond0. I setup the following:

**10-bond0.netdev**

```
[NetDev]
Name=bond0
Kind=bond

[Bond]
Mode=802.3ad
TransmitHashPolicy=layer3+4
MIIMonitorSec=1s
LACPTransmitRate=fast
```

**10-bond0.network**

```
[Match]
Name=bond0

[Network]
Address=10.38.63.1/24
```

**20-enx00145ee890e0.network**

```
[Match]
Name=enx00145ee890e0

[Network]
Bond=bond0
```

**20-enx00145ee890e1.network**

```
[Match]
Name=enx00145ee890e1

[Network]
Bond=bond0
```

**20-enx00145ee890e2.network**

```
[Match]
Name=enx00145ee890e2

[Network]
Bond=bond0
```

**20-enx00145ee890e3.network**

```
[Match]
Name=enx00145ee890e3

[Network]
Bond=bond0
```

Once up

```
root@server#cat /sys/class/net/bond0/bonding/mode
balance-rr 0
```

If I redefine bond0 into bond1 (I move *bond0* files into *bond1* ones and then adjust the info inside them) then

```
root@server#cat /sys/class/net/bond1/bonding/mode
802.3ad 4
```

Also when introducing bond1 I still get bond0 among the interfaces displayed by "ip link show" so bond0 must be defined somewhere but I don't know where.

I have to say that I have a mixed system nased on the networking and systemd-networkd service.

/etc/network/interface doesn't have any reference to bond0

I do want to get rid if networking in favour of systemd-networks but since I don't have access to the server I have to prepare things carefully and accurately.

I don't know from where the system may get that "balance-rr" and not honouring the 802.3ad in the bond0-related files.

Where can I check further?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the problem

root@brunas:/etc/systemd/network$ systemctl --version
systemd 229

I'm hitting this bug

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7025
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/5971

the workaround as reported in the second link is to create

/etc/modprobe.d/bonding.conf and set

options bonding max_bonds=0